# Sending heightForRow:atIndexPath height value after calculating it in-cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView` that has few cells with different heights. Each row's is dynamically adjusted according to the content it contains.

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UICollectionView` in it that should be resized according to how many cells it has (all the cells should be visible, without inside scrolling).

I also have a `UITableViewCell` with another `UITableView` that should be resized according to how many cells it has (all the cells should be visible, without inside scrolling).

The problem is that I don't have the `contentSize` of the collectionView and the tableView while `heightForRow:atIndexPath` gets called so I can't set the values to something right.

I've tried to set it to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and to set the `cell.contentView.frame.size.height` to the contentSize when it got set (added an observer on "contentSize") but then the cells were on top of each other (the collectionView was ontop of the tableView instead of above it).

The tableView code is a regular tableView code.

The collectionView code is:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout()
let collectionViewFlowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
collectionViewFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 34, height: 50)
```

What is the best way to adjust the size of the tableView and the collectionView?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the content your tableview cell is containing?

Comment: @Pankaj Which one? The main tableView contains 5 different custom cells (custom UIViews, collectionView and tableVIew). The inside tableView contains 2 different types of custom cells

Comment: As you said you don't want to scroll collectionview or tableView then you need to manually calculate size of each and every cell in your CV and TV and you need to pass these height for your main cell.

Comment: @Pankaj Yes but how can I calculate it before `contentSize` is set?

Comment: You need to calculate based on the content in your CV and TV cell, calculate the number of cell and make addition of all the cell height and pass it. this all calculation is depends on UI element in your TV and CV cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ask UITableView to adjust its cell height again with this piece of code:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: But when should I call it? How do I know in the tableViewController that both the tableVIew and the collectionView finished loading?

Comment: Can you calculate sizes for nested Collection View and Table View at the moment you instantiate parent Table View?

Comment: The collectionView cells size is set by constraints

Comment: It is possible to ask view to calculate their size based on its constraints